# Disable selectItem in SelectOneChoice

Tags: combobox, oracle-adf

Hey guys I'm trying something completely new to me in terms of GUI with ADF. This is my first ADF experience and I really don't know how to do something like this:

I have several SelectOneChoice (let's call them combobox from 1 to 6) with some selectItems (let's call them options: Blank, Slow, Medium, Fast)

Now, I have to make sure that if I choose on combobox 1 - Blank. All the others have the 4 options available.

Then I'll step onto combobox 2 - Medium. In this case, combobox from 3 to 6 can't have the value Fast, because it can't go faster than the combobox "above".

The same goes to all the others combobox, if "Slow" is chosen then all the combos "below" must have only the option "Slow" or "Blank".

How can I do this?

Here's what I've tryed:

```
af:selectOneChoice id="soc2"
binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.soc2}"
autoSubmit="true"                                                                                                  

    valueChangeListener="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.disableLowerLevelsA}">
<af:selectItem
id="si48"
binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si48}"/>
<af:selectItem label="Slow"
value="slow" id="si3"                                                                                                      binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si3}"/>                                                                                      <af:selectItem label="Medium"                                                                                                       value="medium"                                                                                                       id="si5"                                                                                                       binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si5}"/>                                                                                       <af:selectItem label="Fast"                                                                                                      value="fast" id="si4"
binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si4}"/>
</af:selectOneChoice>
<af:selectOneChoice id="soc5"
binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.soc5}"
partialTriggers="soc2">
<af:selectItem                                                                                                       id="si49"                                                                                                      binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si49}"/>                                                                                       <af:selectItem label="Slow"                                                                                                       value="slow"                                                                                                      id="si12"                                                                                                      binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si12}"/>                                                                                       <af:selectItem label="Medium"                                                                                                      value="medium"                                                                                                      id="si14"               

                                                                                    binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si14}"/>                                                                                        <af:selectItem label="Fast"                                                                                                       value="fast"                                                                                                       id="si13"                                                                                                       binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si13}"/>                                                                                 </af:selectOneChoice>
```

And so on... I've added the trigger and listener to the respective combos. However when I change the content of the first combobox (i.e.: Medium) the other keep all the options visible.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the valueChangeListener of the first SelectOneChoice, get the Viewcriteria programmatically of the second SelectOneChoice and make sure to send the ID column **(not selected value)** of first SelectOneChoice as bind variable.
Also set the viewcriteria to accept this bind variable and execute query with `less than or equal to` assuming the ID's are sorted in ascending order.

```
//To get VC and execute it
    ViewObjectImpl vo = getEmployeesView();
    ViewCriteria vc = vo.getViewCriteria("findEmployeeVC");
    vo.applyViewCriteria(vc);
    vo.setNamedWhereClauseParam("pEmployeeId", employeeId);
    vo.executeQuery();
```

Do not forget to PPR the second SelectOneChoice to refresh the LOV after the first SelectOneChoice  is selected.